# DirectX 11 screenshot capture, multisampled texture, black screen problem

Tags: directx, directx-11, screen-capture

I am trying to take a DirectX 11 screenshot through Present hook. Backbuffer is multisampled, I use ResolveSubresource but still get a black screen.  Tried variations of ResolveSubresource calls, same result. Tried enabling debug layer, there is no messages about CopyResource or ResolveSubresource calls. Here is the code, any help is appreciated.

```
BOOL
D3D11CreateTextureCopyWithCPUAccess(
    __in ID3D11Device* dev,
    __in ID3D11Texture2D* texFrom,
    __out ID3D11Texture2D** cpuAccessTexOut
)
{
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    do {

        if (!dev || !texFrom || !cpuAccessTexOut) break;

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC texFromDesc{};

        texFrom->GetDesc(&texFromDesc);

        LOG_DEBUG(
            L"Texture format %d, sample count %d, usage %d, array size %d, mips levels %d, bind flags %.8x, misc flags %.8x.", 
            texFromDesc.Format, 
            texFromDesc.SampleDesc.Count,
            texFromDesc.Usage,
            texFromDesc.ArraySize,
            texFromDesc.MipLevels,
            texFromDesc.BindFlags,
            texFromDesc.MiscFlags
        );

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC cpuAccessTexDesc{};

        cpuAccessTexDesc.Width = texFromDesc.Width;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.Height = texFromDesc.Height;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.Format = texFromDesc.Format;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.ArraySize = 1;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.BindFlags = 0;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.MipLevels = 1;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.CPUAccessFlags = D3D11_CPU_ACCESS_READ;
        cpuAccessTexDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_STAGING;

        ID3D11Texture2D* cpuAccessTex = nullptr;

        HRESULT hr = dev->CreateTexture2D(&cpuAccessTexDesc, nullptr, &cpuAccessTex);

        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"CreateTexture2D failed, result %.8x.", hr);
            break;
        }

        *cpuAccessTexOut = cpuAccessTex;

        result = TRUE;

    } while (FALSE);


    return result;
}

BOOL
D3D11CopyMultisampledResource(
    __in ID3D11Device* device,
    __in ID3D11DeviceContext* context,
    __in ID3D11Texture2D* texFrom,
    __out ID3D11Texture2D** texToOut
)
{
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    do {

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc{};

        texFrom->GetDesc(&desc);

        UINT support = NULL;

        device->CheckFormatSupport(desc.Format, &support);

        if (!(support & D3D11_FORMAT_SUPPORT_MULTISAMPLE_RESOLVE)) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"Multisample resolving is not supported.");
            break;
        }

        desc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
        desc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;

        ID3D11Texture2D* texTo = NULL;

        HRESULT result = device->CreateTexture2D(&desc, NULL, &texTo);

        if (FAILED(result)) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"Failed to create temp texture, result %.8x.", result);
            break;
        }

        for (ULONG item = 0; item < desc.ArraySize; ++item) {
            for (ULONG level = 0; level < desc.MipLevels; ++level) {
                ULONG index = D3D11CalcSubresource(level, item, desc.MipLevels);
                context->ResolveSubresource(texTo, index, texFrom, index, desc.Format);
            }
        }

        //context->ResolveSubresource(texTo, 0, texFrom, 0, desc.Format);
        *texToOut = texTo;

        result = TRUE;

    } while (FALSE);

    return result;
}

BOOL
D3D11TakeScreenshot(
    IDXGISwapChain* swapChain,
    CAPTURE_HEADER** screenshotOut
)
{
    BOOL result = FALSE;
    ID3D11Device* device = NULL;
    ID3D11DeviceContext* context = NULL;
    ID3D11Texture2D* backBuffer = NULL;
    ID3D11Texture2D* tempTex = NULL;
    ID3D11Texture2D* cpuAccessTex = NULL;

    do {

        if (!swapChain) break;

        DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC swapChainDesc = {0};

        swapChain->GetDesc(&swapChainDesc);

        RECT rect = {0};

        GetClientRect(swapChainDesc.OutputWindow, &rect);

        UINT width = rect.right - rect.left;
        UINT height = rect.bottom - rect.top;

        HRESULT hr = swapChain->GetDevice(__uuidof(ID3D11Device), (void**)&device);

        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"IDXGISwapChain::GetDevice failed, result %.8x.", hr);
            break;
        }

        device->GetImmediateContext(&context);

        hr = swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (void**)&backBuffer);

        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"IDXGISwapChain::GetBuffer failed, result %.8x.", hr);
            break;
        }

        if (!D3D11CreateTextureCopyWithCPUAccess(device, backBuffer, &cpuAccessTex)) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"D3D11CreateTextureCopyWithCPUAccess failed.");
            break;
        }

        D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC desc = {0};

        backBuffer->GetDesc(&desc);

        if (desc.SampleDesc.Count > 1) {
            LOG_DEBUG(L"Multisampled source.");
            if (D3D11CopyMultisampledResource(device, context, backBuffer, &tempTex)) {
                context->CopyResource(cpuAccessTex, tempTex);
            }
        } else {
            context->CopyResource(cpuAccessTex, backBuffer);
        }

        D3D11_MAPPED_SUBRESOURCE res{};

        hr = context->Map(cpuAccessTex, 0, D3D11_MAP_READ, 0, &res);

        if (FAILED(hr)) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"Map failed, result %.8x", hr);
            break;
        }

        VOID* buf = MemAllocVirtual(
            NULL,
            sizeof(CAPTURE_HEADER) + height * res.RowPitch,
            MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE,
            PAGE_READWRITE
        );

        if (!buf) {
            LOG_ERROR(L"VirtualAlloc failed, error %.8x.", GetLastError());
            break;
        }

        CAPTURE_HEADER* hdr = (CAPTURE_HEADER*)buf;

        hdr->success = 1;
        hdr->type = CaptureType_DirectX;
        hdr->cx = width;
        hdr->cy = height;
        hdr->pitch = res.RowPitch;
        
        PUCHAR p = (PUCHAR)buf + sizeof(CAPTURE_HEADER);

        for (ULONG i = 0; i < height; i++) {
            for (ULONG j = 0; j < res.RowPitch / sizeof(ULONG); j++) {
                PUCHAR q = ((PUCHAR)res.pData + i * res.RowPitch + j * 4);
                *p++ = q[2];
                *p++ = q[1];
                *p++ = q[0];
                *p++ = q[3];
            }
        }

        LOG_DEBUG(L"DX11 Screenshot taken %d:%d.", width, height);

        *screenshotOut = hdr;

        result = TRUE;
        
    } while (FALSE);

    if (tempTex) tempTex->Release();

    if (cpuAccessTex) {
        if (context) context->Unmap(cpuAccessTex, 0);
        cpuAccessTex->Release();
    }

    if (backBuffer) {
        backBuffer->Release();
    }

    if (context) {
        context->Release();
    }

    if (device) {
        device->Release();
    }
    
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Where do you get the swap chain from, if it's not yours you can't really do this. For gettting screen shots the best is to use DXGI Desktop Duplication API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3ddxgi/desktop-dup-api

Comment: Swapchain I get from Present routine hook, everything works correctly, if backbuffer is not multisampled.